# `expected 200` error in Rspec test for `get` API request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, endpoint

I'm trying to write some rspec tests to check API endpoints for an API-only application.

**Testing error**

```
Failure/Error: expect( res ).to be_success
       expected 200 to respond to `success?`
```

But if the same call (with full api url) is made from another application it works fine and returns a response.

**Example from other application:**

```
res = RestClient.get "site.io/api/v1/projects/1"
p JSON.parse(res)
```

**Blog example I'm trying to follow:** (http://matthewlehner.net/rails-api-testing-guidelines/).

```
# spec/requests/api/v1/messages_spec.rb
describe "Messages API" do
  it 'sends a list of messages' do
    FactoryGirl.create_list(:message, 10)

    get '/api/v1/messages'

    json = JSON.parse(response.body)

    # test for the 200 status-code
    expect(response).to be_success

    # check to make sure the right amount of messages are returned
    expect(json['messages'].length).to eq(10)
  end
end
```

**My Application**

/requests/projects_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Project do
  describe "show_project" do

      before do
          @project1 = create(:project)
      end

      it "Checks if responds successfully" do
        res = get '/api/v1/projects/1'
        expect( res ).to be_success
      end
  end
end
```

/factories/projects.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :project do
    name "Thing"
    key "123123"
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
namespace :api, :defaults => { :format => 'json'} do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :projects, only: [:create, :show]
      end
    end
end
```

I don't have much experience with testing, so if anyone can point me in the correct direction I would really really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Rspec Request Specs, your call to `get '/api/v1/projects/1'` doesn't need to captured by your `res` variable. Spec Request tests automatically set the value of `response` when `get '/api/v1/projects/1'` is run. The example you're following is correct, it just looks like your missing some knowledge about how much Rspec is handling for you behind the scenes. This makes your test simpler:

```
it "Checks if responds successfully" do
  get '/api/v1/projects/1'
  expect(response).to be_success
end
```

In Rspec Request tests, `response` is automatically setup by the call the `get` without you needing to do anything extra.